# Determine all the positive integers $n\geq 3$, such that $1+{n\choose 1}+{n\choose 2}+{n\choose 3}\vert 2^{2000}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all the positive integers $n\geq 3$, such that $$1+{n\choose 1}+{n\choose 2}+{n\choose 3}\vert 2^{2000}$$

Any hint please!!, I prove that ${n\choose 3}+{n\choose 2}={n+1\choose 3}$ and other things, but I don't see how find the integers. Regards

Comment: $1+{n\choose 1}+{n\choose 2}+{n\choose 3}$ is a cubic in $n$.  Have you written it out?  You need it to be a power of $2$  Have you tried some small $n$? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$n+1+\dfrac{(n+1)n(n-1)}3=\dfrac{(n+1)(n^2-n+3)}3$$

Now $n^2-n+3=n(n+1)-2(n+1)+5$

$\implies(n+1,n^2-n+3)|5$

But $(n+1,n^2-n+3)\ne5$ as then $5|(n+1)$ but $5\nmid2^{2000}$

$\implies(n+1,n^2-n+3)=1$

So, one of them must be $\pm1$